# Instance of UIView subclass is not full screen even if its frame is the window bounds property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    CGRect frame = self.window.bounds;
    BNRHypnosisView *firstView = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.window addSubview:firstView];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The instance of BNRHypnsosisView (subclass of UIView), firstView,  has its frame equal to window bounds. Why it isn't full screen?

EDIT: In BNRHypnosis View , I had a @property (nonatomic) CGRect frame. That's the only thing I had in this subclass. After I deleted it ( i've seen i wasn't using it anywhere ) , everything worked fine. Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: You should not add views to windows directly. Use a `UIViewController`. It will also take care of rotation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declared "frame" property override the existing property "frame" of UIView. It is a fundamental property of any UIView in iOS. If you override it, you have to call `[super setFrame:<frameValue>]` in your implementation to not loose the base and mandatory functionnality.

This declared property is not present in the actual implementation of BNRHypnosisView on GitHub: https://github.com/rahims/iOS-Programming-The-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Guide/blob/master/Chapter-5/Hypnosister/Hypnosister/BNRHypnosisView.h